# Реализация приема данных по UART на 1986VE92U milandr

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, uart

Работаю с отладочной платой на отечественный микроконтроллер 1986ВЕ92 от компании Milandr. Реализую прием и передачу данных через интерфейс RS-232C (встроенный на отладочную плату), для общения с МК и считывания получаемых/отправляемых данных использую программу "Terminal" версии 1.9b, для написания и отладки прошивки "Keil uVision 5". Если с передачей я разобрался(однозначно меняется скорость передачи и видно, что что-то посылается), то с приемом разобраться никак не могу. Перепроверил все пины уже несколько раз, пробовал менять порты, проверял метод загрузки на плате. Ситуация так и не сдвинулась с мертвой точки: передача работает, прием - нет. Прикладываю код на C, на котором я пытаюсь реализовать режим эхо. При написании основывался на данных видео:
[Передача](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BD21stX79s&list=PL8OgDYWys_b4elAGMjZdIHmWOXBV_jXNm&index=4), [Прием](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoC9dtynekA&list=PL8OgDYWys_b4elAGMjZdIHmWOXBV_jXNm&index=5)

```
#include "MDR32Fx.h"                    // Device header
#include "MDR32F9Qx_rst_clk.h"          // Keil::Drivers:RST_CLK
#include "MDR32F9Qx_port.h"             // Keil::Drivers:PORT
#include "MDR32F9Qx_config.h"           // Keil::Device:Startup
#include "MDR32F9Qx_uart.h"             // Keil::Drivers:UART
#include "MDR32F9Qx_timer.h"            // Keil::Drivers:TIMER

void LED_init(void)
{
    PORT_InitTypeDef PortInit;
    RST_CLK_PCLKcmd(RST_CLK_PCLK_PORTC, ENABLE); // включаем тактирование порта C
    /*** LED 0 ***/
    PortInit.PORT_Pin = PORT_Pin_0; // устанавливаем номер порта 
    PortInit.PORT_OE = PORT_OE_OUT; // устанавливаем направление передачи данных - на выход
    PortInit.PORT_FUNC = PORT_FUNC_PORT; // Режим работы - порт
    PortInit.PORT_MODE = PORT_MODE_DIGITAL; // Режим работы - цифровой
    PortInit.PORT_SPEED = PORT_SPEED_SLOW; // Скорость работы - медленный режим
    PORT_Init(MDR_PORTC, &PortInit); // Передаем структуру порту C
}

uint16_t data;
void UART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(UART_GetITStatusMasked(MDR_UART2, UART_IT_RX) == SET) // если бит прерывания по приему установлен
    {
        UART_ClearITPendingBit(MDR_UART2, UART_IT_RX); // сбросить его
        data = UART_ReceiveData(MDR_UART2); // записать принятые данные в переменную
        UART_SendData(MDR_UART2, data); // выдать выдать их обратно
    }
}

void UART_init(void)
{
    PORT_InitTypeDef GPIO_Init; // инициализировать структуру настроек пина
    UART_InitTypeDef UART_user_Init; // инициализировать структуру настроек UART

    RST_CLK_PCLKcmd(RST_CLK_PCLK_PORTD, ENABLE); // включить тактирования порта A, потому что на порте D - P1 это альтернативный TX, а PD0 - это альтернативный RX
    // настройки пинов
    GPIO_Init.PORT_Pin        = PORT_Pin_1; // TX 
  GPIO_Init.PORT_OE         = PORT_OE_OUT; // ОТПРАВКА
  GPIO_Init.PORT_PULL_UP    = PORT_PULL_UP_OFF;
  GPIO_Init.PORT_PULL_DOWN  = PORT_PULL_DOWN_OFF;
  GPIO_Init.PORT_PD_SHM     = PORT_PD_SHM_OFF;
  GPIO_Init.PORT_PD         = PORT_PD_DRIVER;
  GPIO_Init.PORT_GFEN       = PORT_GFEN_OFF;
  GPIO_Init.PORT_FUNC       = PORT_FUNC_ALTER; // альтернативные функции
  GPIO_Init.PORT_SPEED      = PORT_SPEED_MAXFAST;
  GPIO_Init.PORT_MODE       = PORT_MODE_DIGITAL;
    PORT_Init(MDR_PORTD, &GPIO_Init); // записать в структуру
    ///
    GPIO_Init.PORT_Pin        = PORT_Pin_0; // RX 
  GPIO_Init.PORT_OE         = PORT_OE_IN; // ПРИЕМ
    PORT_Init(MDR_PORTD, &GPIO_Init); // записать второй пин в структуру
    ////////////////
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(UART2_IRQn); // разрешение на общее прерывание по uart

    RST_CLK_PCLKcmd(RST_CLK_PCLK_UART2, ENABLE); // включить тактирование uart2
    // настройки uart2
    UART_BRGInit(MDR_UART2, UART_HCLKdiv1);
    UART_user_Init.UART_BaudRate = 9600; 
  UART_user_Init.UART_WordLength = UART_WordLength8b;
  UART_user_Init.UART_StopBits = UART_StopBits1;
  UART_user_Init.UART_Parity = UART_Parity_No;
  UART_user_Init.UART_FIFOMode = UART_FIFO_OFF;
  UART_user_Init.UART_HardwareFlowControl = UART_HardwareFlowControl_TXE | UART_HardwareFlowControl_RXE;
    // и на прием и на передачу

  UART_Init(MDR_UART2, &UART_user_Init); // записать в структуру

    UART_ITConfig(MDR_UART2, UART_IT_RX, ENABLE); // прерывание

    UART_Cmd(MDR_UART2, ENABLE); // включить uart2
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t count = 0;
    LED_init();
    UART_init();
    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

Никак не могу понять в чём ошибка, пожалуйста, помогите.

Мой вопрос о:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю подробностей, но могу дать общие рекомендации, как научиться работать с СОМ-портами.

1. Не бывает так, что Вы подобрали параметры СОМ-порта на запись, а на чтение они не работают.  Они всегда одинаковые.
2. Начинать надо всегда с попытки ЧТЕНИЯ:
3. Подключаем СОМ порт ARM-а к порту Вашего  PC.
4. На РС запускаем Putty, или нечто вроде того.
5. В настройках Putty задаём самую нижнюю частоту.
6. Включаем ARM
7. Если в окне Putty посыпались какие-то символы - значит частоту мы угадали.
8. Если не угадали - выключаем ARM, поднимаем частоту и всё повторяем
9. Размер байта (сегодня) - почти 100% равен 8 бит
10. Осталось подобрать стоп-бит и чётность. Всего 4 комбинации.
11. После того, как на экране появились читаемые символы - входим в диалогс uBoot (путём нажатия любой клавиши в первые 3 секунды) и НАСТРАИВАЕМ параметры СОМ-порта так, как нам хочется.
12. Запоминаем настройки и используем их в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, вопрос исчерпан. Прикладываю код для приема данных из "Terminal". Ответ нашелся на форуме разработчика, по этой ссылке: 
[Topic](http://forum.milandr.ru/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=1617&p=10975#p10936)

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "MDR32F9Qx_config.h"
#include "MDR32Fx.h"
#include "MDR32F9Qx_uart.h"
#include "MDR32F9Qx_port.h"
#include "MDR32F9Qx_rst_clk.h"
#include "MDR32F9Qx_eeprom.h"

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
static PORT_InitTypeDef PortInit;
static UART_InitTypeDef UART_InitStructure;
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  Main program.
  * @param  None11
  * @retval None
  */
int main (void)
{
   RST_CLK_HSEconfig(RST_CLK_HSE_ON);
   while(RST_CLK_HSEstatus() != SUCCESS);

   /* Configures the CPU_PLL clock source */
   RST_CLK_CPU_PLLconfig(RST_CLK_CPU_PLLsrcHSEdiv1, RST_CLK_CPU_PLLmul10);

   /* Enables the CPU_PLL */
   RST_CLK_CPU_PLLcmd(ENABLE);
   if (RST_CLK_CPU_PLLstatus() == ERROR) {
      while (1);
   }

   /* Enables the RST_CLK_PCLK_EEPROM */
   RST_CLK_PCLKcmd(RST_CLK_PCLK_EEPROM, ENABLE);
   /* Sets the code latency value */
   EEPROM_SetLatency(EEPROM_Latency_3);

   /* Select the CPU_PLL output as input for CPU_C3_SEL */
   RST_CLK_CPU_PLLuse(ENABLE);
   /* Set CPUClk Prescaler */
   RST_CLK_CPUclkPrescaler(RST_CLK_CPUclkDIV1);

   /* Select the CPU clock source */
   RST_CLK_CPUclkSelection(RST_CLK_CPUclkCPU_C3);

  /* Enables the HSE clock on PORTF */
  RST_CLK_PCLKcmd(RST_CLK_PCLK_PORTF,ENABLE);

  /* Fill PortInit structure*/
  PortInit.PORT_PULL_UP = PORT_PULL_UP_OFF;
  PortInit.PORT_PULL_DOWN = PORT_PULL_DOWN_OFF;
  PortInit.PORT_PD_SHM = PORT_PD_SHM_OFF;
  PortInit.PORT_PD = PORT_PD_DRIVER;
  PortInit.PORT_GFEN = PORT_GFEN_OFF;
  PortInit.PORT_FUNC = PORT_FUNC_OVERRID;
  PortInit.PORT_SPEED = PORT_SPEED_MAXFAST;
  PortInit.PORT_MODE = PORT_MODE_DIGITAL;

  /* Configure PORTF pins 1 (UART2_TX) as output */
  PortInit.PORT_OE = PORT_OE_OUT;
  PortInit.PORT_Pin = PORT_Pin_1;
  PORT_Init(MDR_PORTF, &PortInit);

  /* Configure PORTF pins 0 (UART2_RX) as input */
  PortInit.PORT_OE = PORT_OE_IN;
  PortInit.PORT_Pin = PORT_Pin_0;
  PORT_Init(MDR_PORTF, &PortInit);


  /* Select HSI/2 as CPU_CLK source*/
  //RST_CLK_CPU_PLLconfig (RST_CLK_CPU_PLLsrcHSIdiv2,0);

  /* Enables the CPU_CLK clock on UART2 */
  RST_CLK_PCLKcmd(RST_CLK_PCLK_UART2, ENABLE);

  /* Set the HCLK division factor = 1 for UART2*/
  UART_BRGInit(MDR_UART2, UART_HCLKdiv1);

  /* Initialize UART_InitStructure */
  UART_InitStructure.UART_BaudRate                = 115000;
  UART_InitStructure.UART_WordLength              = UART_WordLength8b;
  UART_InitStructure.UART_StopBits                = UART_StopBits1;
  UART_InitStructure.UART_Parity                  = UART_Parity_No;
  UART_InitStructure.UART_FIFOMode                = UART_FIFO_ON;
  UART_InitStructure.UART_HardwareFlowControl     = UART_HardwareFlowControl_RXE | UART_HardwareFlowControl_TXE;

  /* Configure UART2 parameters*/
  UART_Init (MDR_UART2,&UART_InitStructure);

  /* Enables UART2 peripheral */
  UART_Cmd(MDR_UART2,ENABLE);

  uint8_t tmp_data;

  while (1)
  {
    /* Check TXFE flag */
    while (UART_GetFlagStatus (MDR_UART2, UART_FLAG_RXFE) == SET);

    tmp_data = UART_ReceiveData(MDR_UART2);

    UART_SendData(MDR_UART2, tmp_data);

    while (UART_GetFlagStatus (MDR_UART2, UART_FLAG_TXFE) != SET);
  }
}
```